# Finding min in 2D Array

Tags: c

```
int main (void) {

const int table[a][b]={{4,2,7},{6,-8,-13}};
int minvals[a];
int i, j;

int min = table[0][0];

for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
    for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
    {
     if (table[i][j] < min){
     min = table[i][j];
     printf("The row's lowest value is %d\n", min);
     }
    }
    }
return (0);
}
```

I am trying to find the minimum in each array when I run my code I get 2 and -8 as opposed to -13 anyone see why it would provide -8 and not -13?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

Your codes inner loop only iterates to a-1, but should until b-1.
Since a, at a guess, is 2 and b is 3, the inner loop is too short and never checks 7 and -13. While ignoring 7 is fine, ignoring -13 causes your problem.
Whatever a and b are using as a definition, which is not shown, my guess should be good enough to name this the core of the problem.

I.e.

```
for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
```

->

```
for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
```

There is another problem, "luckily" hidden by the fact that the second sets minimum is lower than the first ones(with and without the error named above).
Double check when you want to reset your `min`. I guess you want to do that outside of the inner loop, but inside the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your second loop `for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)` replace the `a` with `b` and you should have it working, it will be like this `for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)`.